.NET 6 to 8 Update: System.InvalidOperationException: The configuration is invalid. Creating the instance for type AugmentedRealityController failed
I have a Web App where I just updated the target framework from .NET 6 to 8 and updated all the microsoft packages to 8.0.4. Now I always get this exception when starting:
Application startup exception
System.InvalidOperationException: The configuration is invalid. Creating the instance for type AugmentedRealityController failed. Property set method not found.
 ---> SimpleInjector.ActivationException: Property set method not found.
 ---> System.ArgumentException: Property set method not found.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object value, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object value, Object[] index)
   at evoTrace.Web.Api.Security.ValidationParametersBuilder.<get_ValidationParametersOptionsMapperAction>b__8_0(TokenValidationParameters parameters) in C:\Projekte\evoTraceGS\src\Core\Web\evoTrace.Web.Api\Security\ValidationParametersBuilder.cs:line 52
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigureNamedOptions`1.Configure(String name, TOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.UnnamedOptionsManager`1.get_Value()
   at evoTrace.Core.Security.JwtValidator..ctor(IOptions`1 validationParameters) in C:\Projekte\evoTraceGS\src\Core\Core\evoTrace.Core.Security\JwtValidator.cs:line 21
   at lambda_method47(Closure)
   at SimpleInjector.Scope.CreateAndCacheInstanceInternal(ScopedRegistration registration, Dictionary`2 cache)
   at SimpleInjector.Scope.GetInstanceInternal(ScopedRegistration registration)
   at lambda_method48(Closure)
   at SimpleInjector.Scope.CreateAndCacheInstanceInternal(ScopedRegistration registration, Dictionary`2 cache)
   at SimpleInjector.Scope.GetInstanceInternal(ScopedRegistration registration)
   at lambda_method50(Closure)
   at SimpleInjector.Scope.CreateAndCacheInstanceInternal(ScopedRegistration registration, Dictionary`2 cache)
   at SimpleInjector.Scope.GetInstanceInternal(ScopedRegistration registration)
   at SimpleInjector.Scope.GetInstance[TImplementation](ScopedRegistration registration, Scope scope)
   at lambda_method52(Closure)
   at SimpleInjector.Scope.CreateAndCacheInstanceInternal(ScopedRegistration registration, Dictionary`2 cache)
   at SimpleInjector.Scope.GetInstanceInternal(ScopedRegistration registration)
   at lambda_method58(Closure)
   at SimpleInjector.Scope.CreateAndCacheInstanceInternal(ScopedRegistration registration, Dictionary`2 cache)
   at SimpleInjector.Scope.GetInstanceInternal(ScopedRegistration registration)
   at lambda_method244(Closure)
   at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildAndReplaceInstanceCreatorAndCreateFirstInstance()
   at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.GetInstance()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.GetInstance()
   at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.VerifyInstanceCreation()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.VerifyInstanceCreation()
   at SimpleInjector.Container.VerifyInstanceCreation(InstanceProducer[] producersToVerify, Scope verificationScope)
   at SimpleInjector.Container.VerifyThatAllRootObjectsCanBeCreated(Scope verificationScope)
   at SimpleInjector.Container.VerifyInternal(Boolean suppressLifestyleMismatchVerification)
   at SimpleInjector.Container.Verify(VerificationOption option)
   at SimpleInjector.Container.Verify()
   at evoTrace.Web.Api.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) in C:\Projekte\evoTraceGS\src\Core\Web\evoTrace.Web.Api\Startup.cs:line 212
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeDirectByRefWithFewArgs(Object obj, Span`1 copyOfArgs, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeWithFewArgs(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNetCore.RequestScopingStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNetCore.RequestScopingStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

I don't even know why it shows something with AugmentedRealityController because the whole app has nothing to do with that.
The ValidationParametersBuilder Class where the error occurs looks like this:
internal class ValidationParametersBuilder
    {
        internal ValidationParametersBuilder()
        {     
            var secretKey = ConfigReader.ReadStringValue(EnvVars.JWT_SECRET_KEY);

            var issuer = ConfigReader.ReadStringValue(EnvVars.JWT_ISSUER);

            var audience = ConfigReader.ReadStringValue(EnvVars.JWT_AUDIENCE);

            var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secretKey));
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
            ValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidIssuer = issuer,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidAudience = audience,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,
                RequireExpirationTime = false,
                ValidateLifetime = true,           
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            };
        }

        public SigningCredentials SigningCredentials { get; }

        public TokenValidationParameters ValidationParameters { get; }

        public Action<TokenValidationParameters> ValidationParametersOptionsMapperAction =>
            (parameters) =>
            {
                foreach (var propertyInfo in ValidationParameters.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(ValidationParameters);
                    if (value != null)
                    {
                        propertyInfo.SetValue(parameters, value); // <---- exception here
                    }
                }
            };
    }

And the relevant part of the Startup.cs class:
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            AdjustEnvironment(env);

            app.UseSimpleInjector(_container);
            app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlingMiddleware>(_container);
            app.UseHealthChecks("/health", new HealthCheckOptions
            {
                ResultStatusCodes =
                {
                    [HealthStatus.Healthy] = StatusCodes.Status200OK,
                    [HealthStatus.Degraded] = StatusCodes.Status200OK,
                    [HealthStatus.Unhealthy] = StatusCodes.Status503ServiceUnavailable
                },
                AllowCachingResponses = false
            });
            app.UseRouting();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseCors(ConfigureSecurity.CORS_ALLOW_ANY_ORIGINS);
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseCors(ConfigureSecurity.CORS_ALLOW_SPECIFIC_ORIGINS);
            }

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseMiddleware<NotificationMiddleware>(_container);

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

        
            _container.Verify();

What might be the problem there?

Hi, can you provide your configuration in the startup or program class ? It seems an error with registration/wiring to me.

Sounds like trying to set a value of a property that possibly has a getter only. Happens with reflection, that's why reflection should be used with extra caution.

I added some of the startup.cs file. The error only occured after updating the target framework and the Microsoft packages.

The error occurs in the ValidationParametersBuilder.ValidationParametersOptionsMapperAction getter. It's not related to DI but your own code that tries to call SetValue on a type property without checking if it's settable. At the very least add logging code to see the full type name and property are involved.

The code has other issues as well. You never see Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes because no system uses the 7-bit US-ASCII codepage since the 1970s-80s. Binary values like token keys are typically converted to text using BASE64 encoding. The first 33 characters of the US-ASCII codepage are unprintable control characters like Bell (0x07) and Null (0x00)
